# $http not working in a WEBAPI and Angularjs app, post integrating requireJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, requirejs

for my web app, I integrated RequireJS to AngularJS + ASP.NET WEB API Application. However now the $http service is not able to fetch the data.

I took reference from :  [this Dan Wahlin Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx) to set up require js for dynamically loading of controllers.

My controller code:

```
    'use strict';

define(['app'], function (app) {

    var CategoryController = function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/Values/GetCategoryProducts', { params: { category: "CLothes" } })
             .success(function (data) {

                 $scope.Products = data;
                 $scope.loading = false;
             })
            .error(function () {
                $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
    };

    app.register.controller('CategoryController',
        ['$scope', '$http', CategoryController]);
});
```

my main js :

```
    require.config({
    baseUrl: '/app'
});
waitSeconds: 0
require(
    [
        'app',
        'AppController/NavCntrl'
    ],
    function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['shoppingApp']);
    });
```

$scope is working without any issues and I am able to pass the values to the view. I set some breakpoints and checked that when controller is called it goes to angular-route.js and then returns an error promise.

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to describe to requirejs where angular and angularRoute are in the directory tree, and then describe them as modules.  https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed provides a really good example of a `require.config`.